# R, how to move the plot axis origin in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm creating a plot with ggplot2 in R.
The 0.0 origin point is in the left-lower corner as usual, but **I would like to move it to the upper-left corner** and **reverse the order of the points**.

I try to explain my intention with the following image. 
I want to move the 0.0 origin to the red 0.0 origin point. Of course, also the content of the y axis points must be reversed.

[image]
To create the plot, I'm using:

```
P = ggplot(plot_data_frame, aes(x=Index, y=dataVector)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

How could I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add

```
P <- P + ylim(40000, 0)
```

if, for example, you choose 40000 to be the upper limit. An example:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = gear)) + geom_point()
```

produces

[image]
whereas

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = gear)) + geom_point() + ylim(5, 3)
```

produces

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `scale_y_reverse` option.

```
P = ggplot(plot_data_frame, aes(x=Index, y=dataVector)) + geom_point() + geom_line()

P + scale_y_reverse()
```

If you want specific limits, you can do so using:

```
P + scale_y_reverse(lim=c(10000,0))
```